# Android get thing clicked in listview to setText

Tags: android

I have two classes, a listview class with many strings and a class with a text view ..
I want when I click on a string on the listview the second class starts and the textView in it is setText to the item clicked ..

I tried:

```
      @Override
      protected void onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
      {
          super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
          String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
          Intent select = new Intent(LV.this, Main.class);
          startActivity(select);
      }
```

and on the second class its

```
S.setText(LV.item);
```

S is the textview

now it appears null ..

Comment: so what is the first activity and what is the second one??

Comment: SO you want to change text in your first activity? You can't change text of a textView that is not in current activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont get data in one method of an activity in another activity, unless you pass the data between activites. They are only locally available to one activities

Use `putExtra` to send data from one activity to another. Now in the second activity recieve that value and set it as text to the TextView

Here for e.g

In the first Activity

```
Intent select = new Intent(LV.this, Main.class);
select.putExtra("item", item)
startActivity(select);
```

In the next activity, receive this

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("item");
}

S.setText(value);
```

Comment: Yup, but they gave me -2 .. i can't, i need 15+ rep

Answer (score 0):

`item` is just a local variable of `onListItemClick()`, you cannot access it statically like you tried too. Use `Intent` to send data to another activity.

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Intent select = new Intent(LV.this, Main.class);
    select.putExtra("itemClicked", item);
    startActivity(select);
}
```

And in your second activity, probably in `onCreate()`:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
S.setText(extras.getString("itemClicked");
```

Answer (score 0):

To send data between Activities use this:

```
@Override
  protected void onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
  {
      super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
      String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
      Intent select = new Intent(LV.this, Main.class);
      select.putExtra("item", item);
      startActivity(select);
  }
```

And in another Activity use this

```
String item = getIntent().getStringExtra("item");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MainActivity

 String listview_array[]={"01634    ABOHAR","080 Bangalore","011 Delhi","Dell Inspiron"};
 lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
    (MainActivity.this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listview_array));
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            for(int i=0;i<listview_array.length;i++)
            {
            if(arg2==i)
            {
                Intent t= new Intent("com.example.listviewsearch.detailview");
                t.putExtra("Extra", listview_array[arg2]);
                startActivity(t);
            }
            }

        }

    });
```

detailview

```
TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    System.out.println("Get Intent done");
    if(extras !=null)
    {
        tv.setText(extras.getString("Extra").toString());

    }
```