# How to take a string from listview and send it to another activity on text view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, textview

```
ListView lv;
String values[] = new String[]{"Hello How r u","I am Fine"};
lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, festival);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,View arg1,int position,long arg3) {
        if(position==0) {
            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this ,SharingActivity.class );
            i.putExtra("extra", values[0]);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}

lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Hi, this is my MainActivity. I want to send "Hello How are you" to SharingActivity using Intent. How? In SharingActivity, i have a TextView. I want to print this message on TextView

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971252/android-get-thing-clicked-in-listview-to-settext/12971887#12971887. You should have a look at this link.

Comment: Please use the code tags when you post code. Your post is very unreadble right now.

Comment: @ShailModi First Accept Some answers then i can help you.

Comment: If you have your answer, accept it. If you dont accept answers people wont want to answer your questions in the future

Answer (score 2):

> You can use this code another activity.

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String mValue = extras.getString("profileId");
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setText(mValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

u already had added the string "how are you " in intent. so now u just have to do this in ur `SharingActivity` :---

```
TextView textView = (TextView) this.findViewById(<ur textview id>);
String urText = getIntent.getExtras().get("extra");
textView.setText(urText);
```